# How to claim bitcoin cash for Bitcoin Wallet backup created before 1st August2017?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-wallet-app, android

I use this bitcoin wallet for android for my bitcoins..
[image]

I had created backup well before 1st August 2017 from Safety>>Backup My Wallet..
The backup is encrypted with name 
bitcoin-wallet-backup-2017-xx-xx

How can I claim Bitcoin Cash for these bitcoins?

I have read about decrypting wallet using openssl but output is random symbols since the wallet is in protobuf format..

Can you explain to me the procedure for claiming bitcoin cash in detailed steps?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 as my OS on laptop if it is needed for decryption process..

Also now If I move these bitcoins to another wallet, say Electruk them Can I use the other simplified process? Or I have to use that baclup Bitcoin Wallet for android?